Car Chase movie - Student chased by 3 bad guys
I'm looking for a chase-action-thriller movie or TV movie, released between 1995 - 2005.
Language: English
Country: USA (I guess)
Story : At the end of a study day, a guy finds his colleague at university in trouble when 3 foolish bad guys are harassing her. So he takes her and they escape in his car, and the 3 criminals chase after them throughout the movie. In one scene, the hero drives his car between two trucks on two wheels, the same trick Jason Statham did in Transporter 3. Then they drive from the freeway to a farm area, and finally the three criminals drive their car over the side of a mountain.
Details: The 3 bad guys run after the boy and girl all day until night, and the next day they continue the chase. Almost every scene in the film takes place during the car chase, just like "Duel" (1971)  “Dirty Mary Crazy Larry” (1974).
Date: I didn't recognize any of the actors, because I saw that movie when I was a kid on TV. But I remember at around the same time I saw the horror movie "Wrong Turn", which came out in 2003, so I think that movie could have been released at the same time, or a few years earlier.

i didn't recognize actors because i saw that movie when i was a kid on tv
:)

suggest a title

check other questions for title inspiration; regardless, the title should shortly describe the movie you're searching for

I found the movie.
It has the same name of a movie I asked before. Road Rage (2000)
the other question was about Road Rage (1999)
Two nice movies.
IMDb plot summary of the movie: 

The highway to hell runs straight through a college campus in this compelling thriller about a killer truck. After helping a pretty co-ed out of a nasty domestic situation, Jim Travis gives the girl a lift home. But once on the road, the situation takes a white-knuckle twist as Jim gets into a frightening duel with a crazy truck driver. 


Feel free to accept your own answer too
